# Resizing windows in curses

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I have several tiled windows in curses, initialized like this

```
int row, col;
getmaxyx(stdscr, row, col);
WINDOW* a = newwin(row, col/2, 0, 0);
WINDOW* b = newwin(row, col/2, 0, col/2);
box(a, 0, 0);
box(b, 0, 0);
/* Refresh stdscr and windows...
...
*/
```

If the user resizes the terminal, I would like to resize the windows accordingly, what's the best way to do this? All I can think of is deleting the old windows and making new ones, but that can be kind of tedious when I'm dealing with multiple windows

Comment: Can you not use [wresize()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/wresize)?

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I couldn't find that function in the man pages, only mvwin.